# Why isn't the ImageView/background show in storyboard

Tags: uiimageview, xcode5

I have added an ImageView as a background and added a .png image but the actual image does not show in storyboard but when i run it shows.

Anyone know why this is the case?

See picture:

[image: The picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve this and it turned out to be the name of the .png that caused the problem. When changed "iphone5_frosty-568h@2x.png" to a shorter name it suddenly worked.